# What is the Parquet summary file?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

On Apache's official website, [this is the official explanation of this parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkS4j.png):

> When true, the Parquet data source merges schemas collected from all data files, otherwise the schema is picked from the summary file or a random data file if no summary file is available.

In fact, my question is, what is the **summary file**?

Answer (score 1):

Apache Parquet uses metadata to store all information required to load the data from a file, like column metadata, dictionaries row groups and so on.

The format is designed to keep this metadata embeded in the file itself, or stored a separate file. This is what `summary` file is.

Answer (score 0):

Parquet summary file contains a collection of footers from actual Parquet data files in a directory.  It can be used to skip RowGroups when reading w/o fetching the footer from each individual Parquet file which may be expensive if you have a lot of files and/or on Blob stores.

https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/blob/65b95fb72be8f5a8a193a6f7bc4560fdcd742fc7/parquet-hadoop/src/main/java/org/apache/parquet/hadoop/ParquetFileReader.java#L407

Answer (score -3):

Parquet storage format is the columnar oriented file format, that means data for a particular column for all the rows will be stored adjacent to each other, which results in two main benefits - better compression ratio and increased query performance.